# Initialize array of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

I'm trying to make some test data with which to test some functionality of my code. To this end, I need a `double[][]`. I am trying to do with a function that takes a `double[][]` as an input parameter and copying onto it a local variable containing the test data. However, I get an error that I don't quite understand (I'm sure it's a very basic error, which is why I'm unable to Google it), understanding/fixing which I'd appreciate any help.

```
private void makeData(double[][] patterns)
{
    double[][] data = new double[2][];
    // exists so that I can change `data` easily, without having to change the core functionality of copying it over to `patterns`
    data[0] = {1.0,8.0}; // error!
    // copy over everything from data into patterns
}
```

The line marked in the above code is giving me the error `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new objects can be used as a statement`. To this, my reaction is "Isn't `data[0] = {1.0,8.0};` an assignment?

I'm fairly confused, so I'd appreciate any help

Comment: you're using a 2 dimensional array and your second statement became 1 dimensional array

Comment: `new double[]{,}` (I presume the data type is required)

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo: Thank you. That is exactly the explanation that I needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace:

```
data[0] = {1.0,8.0};
```

by:

```
data[0] = new double[] { 1.0, 8.0 };
```

The compiler has to know explicitly what to assign to `data[0]`. It doesn't infer it from the type of `data[0]`.

Comment: You can actually type `new[] {...}` because it *can* infer the type from the contents of the initializer.

Comment: I never do it for numbers because its easy to get lost with integers, floats, doubles, etc. And the type is infered, not from the type of `data[0]`, but from the content of the initializer.

Comment: Yes, I said that it would infer the type based on the contents of the array.  Note that if it inferred the wrong type then it wouldn't compile; if, for example, the contents were of type `int` and it made it an `int[]` then you'd get an error assigning that to a `double[]`, so the code would remain clear in context.

Answer (score 5):

You want to do

```
data[0] = new[] {1.0, 8.0};
```

The curly brace initializers are only valid if you're creating an object/array. They don't work by themselves.

You can specify the type specifically:

```
data[0] = new double[] {1.0, 8.0};
```

But you don't have to if the compiler can infer the right type (which, in your case, it can).

Answer (score 1):

You should to initialize your subarray first.

```
double[][] data = new double[2][];
data[0] = new double[] {1.0f, 8.0f};
```